# Number of Workflow instances that could be "In Progress"

Tags: designer-workflow

I have created a SharePoint Designer Workflow for a document library. Whenever the user uploads a document the workflow is started and is completed only when they fill the meta data for it.

The issue is many users upload a document and keep it checked out. The number of workflow instances `In Progress` increases. If it exceeds 10, the workflow does not send any mails for new documents but the status says `Completed`.

Are there any limitations for the instaces in status `In Progress`?